# read latex commands in rst files with sphinx

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, tex

I'm pretty new with latex and I'm trying to combine latex rules within a sphinx project created with `sphinx-quickstart`.

I followed [this guide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/sphinx/AdvancedUsersManual/RenderingPdf/CustomizingRendering.html) in order to understand how to create custom commands in latex. Looking inside the sphinx generated `.tex` file I see that my custom stylesheet is correctly imported and read.

The question now is: how can I call the commands created in the `latex-stylesheet` in all the `.rst` files?

The aim is pretty simple: in the `latex-stylesheet` I define a role in order to have some red text that I want to call in the `.rst` files with `` :redtext:`this should be red` ``.

I tried with:

- :command:`text`
- .. class:
- .. role:

but none worked.

Did someone have some useful suggestion?